# How to know if the JTextField is empty?

Tags: java

I am building a GUI  for some Java project. I need to validate what user input on JTextField. But I have a small problem.

The JTextField is for entering Integer. So, I did try and catch for NumberFormatException. The question is: if the user fires an action (press Enter) without writing anything in the JTextField even space, How could I handle this?

```
int id = 0;
try {
id = Integer.parseInt(tfID.getText());
} catch (NumberFormatException e1 ) {
    if (tfID.getText()==null) //This does not work
        idError.setText("Enter an Integer");
    else
        idError.setText("Intgers only accepted");
}
```

I want to show a message on another JTextfield (which is idError in this case) to tell the user to enter an Integer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe a simple `if (tfID.getText()=="")` ?

Comment: I think that `if( tfID.getText().equals("") )` should work

Comment: Check with .equals() instead of == operator

Comment: @Kurohige, Thanks. It works.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using:

```
if (tfID.getText()==null)
```

use:

```
if( tfID.getText().equals("") )
```

which will return **true** if and only if the two strings are equal, which is here **tfID.getText()** and **("")**.

Thanks for you all.

Comment: I was about to answer it, but that looks fine to me.